# Firestore Listerner not working as expected

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My web application requires me to use firestore listener for a document jkl. Instead of printing the updated value once, it is repeatedly printing the value even though there is no update in the document jkl.

```
void switchListener() async 
{
  _listener = Firestore.instance
  .collection('abc')
  .document('def')
  .collection('ghi')
  .document('jkl')
  .snapshots()
  .listen((data) => listenerUpdate(data));
}

void listenerUpdate(data) 
{
   String number = data['URL'];
   setState(() {
     _totalDocs = number;
   });
 }
```

Can I get some help on this.

**Updated**

The listener is activated only after clicking on a button.

```
onPressed: () {
   switchListener();  
},

void switchListener() async {
  _listener = Firestore.instance
      .collection('abc')
      .document('def')
      .collection('jkl')
      .document('mno')
        .snapshots()
        .distinct()
        .listen((data) => listenerUpdate(data));

  _listener.cancel();

 }

void listenerUpdate(data) {
    String number =  data['physicianNote'];
    String url =  data['signedURL'];
    setState(() {
      _totalDocs = number;
      _signedurl = url;
    });
    print("totalDoc: "+_totalDocs);
    print("url: "+_signedurl);
    js.context.callMethod("open", [signedurl]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the `distinct()` method after the `snapshots()` method which
skips data events if they are equal to the previous data event. You can find out more from the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/distinct.html).

```dart
void switchListener() async 
{
  _listener = Firestore.instance
  .collection('abc')
  .document('def')
  .collection('ghi')
  .document('jkl')
  .snapshots()
  .distinct() // Will only emit if `snapshots()` emits different data
  .listen((data) => listenerUpdate(data));
}

void listenerUpdate(data) 
{
   String number = data['URL'];
   setState(() {
     _totalDocs = number;
   });
 }
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but still the problem exists.

Comment: @Jasmine can you show the code for the widget from which you call `switchListener()` ?

Comment: I have updated the code. The listener is activated only after a button is clicked.